# How do I start methods in parallel with Parallel.Invoke?

Tags: c#, winforms

I want to execute methods in parallel **without** starting a new thread or a new Task for each method. I am using `Winforms` and targeting `.Net 4.5`

Here's what I want to do. I have a List named accounts, method called `processAccount`, and I want to start `processAccount` for each account in the list. I want to execute the methods in parallel and after quite some reading it looks like `Parallel.Invoke` might be what I need:

```
List<string> accounts = new List<string>();

private static void processAccount(string acc)
{
  //do a lot of things
}

Action[] actionsArray = new Action[accounts.Count];

//how do I do the code below
for (int i = 0; i < accounts.Count; i++)
{
 actionsArray[i] = processAccount(accounts[i]); //  ?????
}

//this is the line that should start the methods in parallel 
Parallel.Invoke(actionsArray);
```

Comment: Looks good what's the problem?

Comment: `Parallel.ForEach(accounts, processAccount);`

Comment: Note you should include any compilation or runtime errors that you encounter in your question.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The problem is that you need to create an Action.  The easiest way to do that is with a lambda.

```
for (int i = 0; i < accounts.Count; i++)
{
    int index = i;
    actionsArray[i] = () => processAccount(accounts(index)); 
}
```

Note that you have to capture the `i` variable inside the loop in the `index` variable so that all the actions don't end up using the same value, that would end up being `accounts.Count` after the `for` loop finishes.

Comment: Worked 100%, just changed the curly brackets around index to square ones. This is exactly the problem I was having. I was testing with console application, simply printing numbers 1 to 10 and instead of 1, 4, 3, 2, 5, etc. I was getting 10, 10, 10 , 10 ....